# React Native - Animated Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I love the React Native animated API but it conflicts heavily with my preferred way of writing components which is completely stateless functional components.

Take this component as an example. How would I make the Image animated without reverting to class syntax and a state variable to drive the Image style?

```
const Logo = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <Animated.Image 
        resizeMode='contain'
        style={styles.image}
        source={require(img/sample.png')}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
)

export default Logo
```

Comment: I mean, if the components has to have state (which since it's animated, most likely), you can't do much, if anything, with class syntax. Functional components are merely presentational with no state, just props.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I would just like some way to insulate it to just animations as I find once a component is opened to state it becomes a dumping ground.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use store to keep animated values of course. But IMO it is bad idea.  Just use classes. You should be more flexible ;)

As alternative you can try https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable with declarative syntax. I didn't use it before but look like it can help.

**UPDATED:** With React Native 0.59 and above you can use hooks inside functional components.

Comment: I guess this library or it's approach of wrapping animation in another component to isolate state is the best way. Cheers.

Answer (score 21):

As farwayer mentioned you can use react hooks.
They were introduced in React 16.8, and added to React Native in version 0.59.

You will have to use both `useState` and `useEffect`. The `useState` will keep the value of a progress bar, while `useEffect` will update it when necessary.

```
const AnimatedComponent = (props)=>{

    // Need to create state first. Setter is not used in this case
    const [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(props.value))

    useEffect(()=>{
        Animated.timing(value, {
            toValue: props.value,
            duration: 100,
        }).start() // < Don't forget to start!
    }, [props.value]) // < Run animation only when props.value changed

    // Apply animated property to your style
    return (
        <Animated.View style={{width: value}} />
    )
}
```

---

For example this is how I implemented a progress bar:

```
const ProgressBar = (props)=>{

    const [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(props.value))

    useEffect(()=>{
        Animated.timing(value, {
            toValue: props.value,
            duration: 100,
        }).start()
    }, [props.value])

    const width = value.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 100],
        outputRange: ['0%', '100%'],
    })

    return (
        <View style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}>
            <Animated.View style={{
                width: width,
                height: '100%',
                backgroundColor: 'green',
            }}></Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**UPTADED**

Comment: This seems like a misuse of useState, no? You're mutating the state variable directly instead of through useState. Would possibly be better to do something like: ```const value = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current```

Comment: @NathanL no, that is how animated is meant to be used within functional component. If there is a violation of paradigm it is inside the animated component. But if you consider it as a part of the framework it it is ok.

Comment: I think that is incorrect, even within React Native's own documentation they useRef. https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#example

Comment: @NathanL I see your point. Perhaps it is better to ask a separate question regarding useRef vs useState in this case.

Comment: width does not works with nativedriver = true right ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are still wondering how to solve this, I manage to do it this way

```js
export const Toggle = () => {
  const progress = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(progress, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [progress]);

  return <LottieView source={require('./json/toggle.json')} autoPlay loop />;
};
```